# Wix installer - how to add files with msi in output folder

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wix

I'm generating a msi and need to add a few files that are *.txt* from my solution into the ***bin*** folder, along with the MSI.

For example, adding a read-me.txt always that a new MSI is generated. This file must not be within the package.

I'd not like to use Build Events (DOS commands) if I have an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **wixproj**, try that:

```
<Project ...>
    <Target Name="AfterBuild">
        <Copy SourceFiles="SourceFile.txt" DestinationFiles="DestFileName.txt" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Where can I find additional information on the Copy element?  I have only found information on CopyFile, not Copy.